# Why does my shared data source become a custom data source when deployed?

Tags: sql-server-2005, reporting-services, visual-studio-2005, datasource

So I have a lot of SSRS reports that I am attempting to deploy with shared data sources.  When I open up the data source in visual studio, "Use shared data source reference" is checked, but when I deploy these reports, the data sources get deployed, but every report seems to have just copied the connection string and set it to use that as a custom data source.  I can go into the properties and manually set them to the shared data source object.  Other than manually setting each individual report to use the shared data source, I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  I was adding a shared datasource to preexisting reports to cut down on the amount of manual changes when switching servers.  However, once a report is deployed, the data source properties in report manager can no longer be changed by visual studio.  The solution is to delete the reports from the report server before redeploying them.  It'll be forced to get the get whatever is defined in the report definition then.

Answer (score 0):

In the Visual Studio report project, if you right-click on the project in Solution Explorer and select "Properties" you should see a Deployment option called "OverwriteDataSources".

This property is set to False by default, meaning that once a report is deployed and further deployments will not change the original data source. You can override this by setting the property to True, allowing you to deploy the updated reports with data source changes.

It's generally a good idea to leave this set to False unless you specifically need to change the data source on the server.